# Sum type with HashMap

Tags: haskell, hashmap, algebraic-data-types, sum-type

The following code triggers an error:

```hs
import           Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap) -- from unordered-containers
import           Data.Text

data Value =
    VText Text
  | VList [Text]
  | VMap HashMap Text Text
  deriving Show
```

The compiler complains that:

```markdown
Expecting two more arguments to ‘HashMap’
  Expected a type, but ‘HashMap’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
  In the type ‘HashMap’
  In the definition of data constructor ‘VMap’
  In the data declaration for ‘Value’typecheck
```

How can I create a sum type like `Value` where one of the constructors takes a `HashMap Text Text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using parenthesis to disambiguate parameters for `HashMap` in `VMap`:

```
data Value =
    VText Text
  | VList [Text]
  | VMap (HashMap Text Text)
  deriving Show
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that I tried every single possible bracket combination except for this particular one... massive thanks

Comment: @Jivan: If you find the conventional `data` syntax confusing, another option is `{-# Language GADTSyntax #-}`, where you write the type of each constructor explicitly: `data Value where { VText :: Text -> Value; VList :: [Text] -> Value; VMap :: HashMap Text Text -> Value; }`. What you had in your original post was equivalent to saying `VMap :: HashMap -> Text -> Text -> Value`; if you tried bracketings like `HashMap(Text, Text)` or `HashMap (Text Text)`, those mean `HashMap -> (Text, Text) -> Value` and `HashMap -> Text Text -> Value` respectively—I hope that clarifies why they wouldn’t work.